# Disable AMD Ryzen integrated graphics card on ubuntu

Tags: amd-graphics, amd-ryzen

I have an integrated graphics card in my Ryzen AMD APU that uses 1 GB of the system's memory. I want to disable it in order to use all the RAM. My laptop has a dedicated graphics card, but in the BIOS there are no options to only use the dedicated graphics card. Can I disable my integrated GPU from Ubuntu?

I have already tried to set `radeon.modeset=0 amdgpu.runpm=0` on `/etc/default/grub` and then recompile GRUB without any success.

Running `sudo lshw -c video` I see two graphics cards at the moment:

```
 *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:fa0-f9f iomemory:fc0-fbf memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:fa00000000-fbffffffff memory:fc00000000-fc01ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:d1080000-d10fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: c5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf irq:50 memory:fc10000000-fc1fffffff memory:fc20000000-fc201fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:d1500000-d157ffff
```

Comment: Hi! I can't help you directly, but note that only using your dedicated GPU will likely have a negative impact on your battery life.

Comment: You need to install the recommended Nvidia drivers and then, using the Nvidia X Server Settings app, you can easily switch graphics (reboot needed). A correction regarding the first comment: Using the dGPU will impact the *autonomy*, i.e., the amount of time you can use the computer with the same battery charge because the dGPU needs a lot more energy but won't impact the *lifetime* of said battery, i.e., its lifespan.

Comment: I know it , but my laptop is always connected on the elettric wire so i don't have problems

Comment: @ChanganAuto I did it but the integrated gpu is always active, my laptop see only 15 Gb of ram. Can you tell me how I can do it from the x server?

Comment: No, if you switch to the dGPU (Nvidia) the iGPU will be turned off. That however has no impact in the assigned memory for the iGPU. And it couldn't be any other way. Keep in mind this machines are designed for Windows where typically the on-demand switching is the default so it must always keep the same amount of shared RAM reserved.

Comment: @ChanganAuto The cambridge dictionary disagrees with you, consider having a look at a dictionary before correcting people on the meaning of words: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/battery-life

Battery life is definitely mostly used to refer to the amount of hours before charging, see some more examples here: https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-increase-laptop-battery-life and here: https://9to5mac.com/2021/11/22/apple-silicon-macbook-pro-battery-life

Just look at the results when googling "battery life". Another correct term for the "lifetime" of a battery is lifespan.